# Exercise 8, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$. Let $B$ be a fixed element of $V$ and let $T_B$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $T_B(A)=AB-BA$. Show that $\text{det}(T_B)=0$.

**My attempt:** Assume towards contradiction, $\text{det}(T_B)\neq 0$. By [exercise 6 section 5.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553308/861687), $T_B$ is invertible, i.e $T_B$ is injective and surjective. $T_B(0)=0\cdot B-B\cdot 0=0$ and $T_B(I_n)=I_n\cdot B-B\cdot I_n=B-B=0$. Since $0\neq I_n$ and $T_B(0)=T_B(I_n)$, we have $T_B$ is not injective. Which contradicts our initial assumption. Hence $\text{det}(T_B)=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

We could have done this problem using direct proof. By contrapositive of exercise 6 section 5.4, $T_B$ is not bijective$\iff$$\text{det}(T_B)=0$. Above we show $T_B$ is not injective. So $T_B$ is not bijective. Thus $\text{det}(T_B)=0$.

**Que:** Can we solve this problem by computing $\text{det}(T_B)$ via [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants)?

Comment: Your proof is correct but note that you didn't use the hypothesis that $\det(T_B)\neq 0$, you just proved it is not injective. For this reason your proof is direct and not via contradiction.

Comment: @N.Pullbacki I think I have use $\text{det}(T_B)\neq 0$ hypothesis to conclude $T_B$ is invertible.